# Op-amp integrator gain from calculation doesn't correspond with real-world measurement

Tags: operational-amplifier

In my integrator circuit, I added one feedback resistor R<sub>2</sub> and one bias compensation resistor R<sub>3</sub>. The values of the components are values I have measured before I applied them on this [PCB Evaluation Board](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/evaluation-hardware-and-software/evaluation-boards-kits/eval-opamp-1.html#eb-overview).

All components are somewhat of *standard* SMD components lying around my soldering iron. I calculated the gain with this formula:

\$ \text{gain}_\text{calc} = \frac{1}{2\pi f R_1 C_f} \approx \underline{\underline{2.9}}\$

The simulation with LTspice gives me the same value.

[image]

[image]

But on my PCB circuit I measured a different gain.

[image]

\$\text{gain}_\text{meas} = \frac{V_{\text{out_rms}}}{V_{\text{in_rms}}} = \frac{5.793\text{ V}}{2.135\text{ V}} \approx \underline{\underline{2.7}}\$.

This leaves me with a voltage difference of V<sub>pp</sub> ≈ 1.127 V, just a bit too much for my gut feeling.

What can cause this difference, and where should I revisit my doings so far to have the values from the simulation equal to the values in the real world?

Comment: What is the tolerance of your 49n9 capacitor? Is its value constant with applied bias?

Comment: @ThePhoton It is a 47 nF capacitor with +-20 % tolerance. The value I used in the simulation is the value I measured before. I can't answer your second question, because I can't assign. Probably the datasheet can help us? [0805 47nF](https://docs.rs-online.com/c6c7/0900766b80027f3b.pdf)

Comment: It's shown in the upper right chart on page 53. But your capacitor is actually pretty good over your +/- 5 V operating range, maybe only +/- 3% due to voltage effects, where you're looking for about a 10% error source.

Comment: If you had been using a 10-V rated part with a similar \$\Delta C/C\$ curve (but scaled to 10 V), you could have been looking at 50% changes in capacitance value.

Comment: You could put your finger on that capacitor and see if heating it up a bit changes the gain any further.

Comment: Look at the waveforms and tell me with 100% confidence that you believe the p-p amplitude of the blue trace is 2.7 times the purple trace.

Comment: @Andyaka The purple trace is 2.7 times of the blue trace, not the other way around. In the scope it looks like the purple is around 19 Vpp, but the measuring tell me other values. A RMS of 5.79 Vrms is equivalent to only 16.37 Vpp. Or do I overseen here something completely?

Comment: @ThePhoton Can it be because my operating range is +- 9 V? Because the Vpp from the output should be at this range. I will test the experiment with the finger tomorrow and will give feedback.

Comment: @Daniel In your previous question, when I said that a resistor is placed across the capacitor, I said 1 M\$\Omega\$ *or higher*. You have to account for that "higher" part when using components, otherwise you could have found out for yourself about [the difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d67V.png) (aka: the answer below is right).

Comment: I haven't a clue what is going on, but when you say "my operating range is +- 9 V", you are using +/- 9 volt supplies? If so, rerun your simulation with those voltages.

Comment: @ThePhoton My finger wasn't a good heater for the capacitor, it adds some parallel resistor to it and I got an offset which caused useless measurement. But I used my soldering iron with 70 °C on it, and it caused a difference of +0.05 V in the V<sub>rms</sub>-measurement. Not that much, I would say. But I see where you are want to lead, and I appreciate your information about the other curve where the capacity changing over the applied voltage.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I have done an equivalent [simulation](https://imgur.com/zMawNh8). For me, there is no difference in gain at f = 50 Hz. But as you mentioned, the answer below tells the truth. Also, it is truth that I should revisit my control systems class because for me these two equivalent gain calculations lead to different results.

Comment: @Daniel Well, I also need to polish my glasses, because I don't know why I saw something about 3 Hz, where there clearly is a gain difference. Oh well, at least the problem is solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are neglecting R2 as part of your feedback impedance in the gain calculation equation. The reactance of Cf at 50 Hz is about 64 k ohms and so the 998 kohms parallel resistor is significant in calculating the total feedback impedance.

To get a rough estimate of the feedback impedance do R2.Xc/(R2+Xc) which gives an estimated feedback impedance of 60 k ohms. 60 k/21.978 k = about 2.7

To calculate the gain accurately you need to include a j term in the capacitor's impedance calculation and calculate the transfer function.

Gain = ((R2/jwC)/(R2+1/jwC))/R1

That is the transfer function and you then need to get that in the form a+jB and derive an expression for the magnitude.

But the quick and easy estimation of the way I mentioned first without including the j term seems to agree with your experimentally derived gain.

Comment: What's about R3?

Answer (score 3):

You have stated that your cap is +/- 20%. You expected a gain of 2.9.

With Vin at 3 volts pk, that is an RMS of 2.12, which corresponds very closely with your scope reading of 2.13.

Now assume that Cf is 20% larger than nominal. From your gain equation, it should be obvious that the gain will be about 20% less, actually 0.833.

0.833 times 2.9 is 2.42, so you are well within tolerance.

To run it another way, a gain of 2.7 can be explained by Cf being large by a factor of 2.9/2.7, or 7.5%. That is eminently reasonable. If you like, you can get a capacitance meter and check.

Comment: I have measured the capacitor. This is the reason the value of the capacitor in the schematic is 49.9 nF and not 47 nF. So I think the difference in gain isn't from the capacitive tolerance because I measured the capacitor before using and take the value for the simulation. I can imagine, that a tolerance with applied operating voltage affected also the difference in gain, like @ThePhoton mentioned in the comments directly under my question.